# How to recursively remove each key from a multi-dimensional(depth not known) python dictionary?

Tags: python

I'm trying to test if server is OK when param is missing, by retriving a dict to remove each key from a dict:

```
data = {'a':'b','c':'d','e':{'aa':'bb'}}
for i in range(len(data)):    
  print "removed ans:",dict(data.items()[:i] + data.items()[i+1:])
```

the answer is like this:

```
removed ans: {'c': 'd', 'e': {'aa': 'bb', 'cc': 'dd'}}
removed ans: {'a': 'b', 'e': {'aa': 'bb', 'cc': 'dd'}}
removed ans: {'a': 'b', 'c': 'd'}
```

but I also need to delete each item in 'e':

```
removed ans: {'c': 'd', 'e': {'aa': 'bb', 'cc': 'dd'}}
removed ans: {'a': 'b', 'e': {'aa': 'bb', 'cc': 'dd'}}
removed ans: {'a': 'b', 'c': 'd'}
removed ans: {'c': 'd', 'e': {'cc': 'dd'}}
removed ans: {'a': 'b', 'e': {'aa': 'bb'}}
```

I think I need to do it in a function, but

1. how can I return different answer each time in a function?
2. how can I go to multi-demension dict?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be accomplished with a recursive generator function:

```
def remove_next_key(my_dict):
    for key, val in my_dict.items():
        new_dict = dict(my_dict)
        if isinstance(val, dict):
            for nested_dict in remove_next_key(val):
                new_dict[key] = nested_dict
                yield new_dict
        new_dict.pop(key)
        yield new_dict

start_dict =  {'a':'b','c':'d','e':{'aa':'bb', 'cc': 'dd'}}

for sub_dict in remove_next_key(start_dict):
    print(sub_dict)
```

Output:

```
{'c': 'd', 'e': {'aa': 'bb', 'cc': 'dd'}}
{'a': 'b', 'e': {'aa': 'bb', 'cc': 'dd'}}
{'a': 'b', 'c': 'd', 'e': {'cc': 'dd'}}
{'a': 'b', 'c': 'd', 'e': {'aa': 'bb'}}
{'a': 'b', 'c': 'd'}
```

Comment: @fio Each time you call the function it will run until it hits a yield statement. It then continues from that point the next time you call it. If the answer solved your issue, feel free to accept it :)

Answer (score -1):

This can be done using a recursive generator.

```
data = {'a': 'b', 'c': 'd', 'e': {'aa': 'bb', 'cc': 'dd'}}

def get_next_test_data(original_data):
    for property in original_data:
        modified_data = dict(original_data)
        modified_data.pop(property)
        yield modified_data
        if isinstance(original_data[property], dict):
            for new_val in get_next_test_data(original_data[property]):
                modified_data = dict(original_data)
                modified_data[property] = new_val
                yield modified_data

for output in get_next_test_data(data):
    print(output)
print("all test cases posted")
```

The above code outputs:

```
{'c': 'd', 'e': {'aa': 'bb', 'cc': 'dd'}}
{'a': 'b', 'e': {'aa': 'bb', 'cc': 'dd'}}
{'a': 'b', 'c': 'd'}
{'a': 'b', 'c': 'd', 'e': {'cc': 'dd'}}
{'a': 'b', 'c': 'd', 'e': {'aa': 'bb'}}
"all test cases posted"
```

Comment: This is exactly the same as my answer which was posted 30 minutes before...

Comment: Sorry, but I'd been writing it for the better part of an hour. I'm not used to python so I was working things out as I went. I saw your answer, but decided there's no point deleting my own.